# Running Time of GCD Function Recursively (Euclid Algorithm)

Tags: c, runtime, time-complexity, recurrence, greatest-common-divisor

I have only been able to find posts about how to implement the gcd function both recursively and iteratively, however I could not find this one. I am sure it's on Stackoverflow however I could not find it so I apologize if it's a duplicate post.

---

I have looked at the analysis on Wikipedia ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Algorithmic_efficiency)) and could not understand their recurrence relation.

Consider the following implementation of the GCD function recursively implemented in C. It has a pre condition that both numbers must be positive, however irrelevant for the run time.

```
int gcd( int const a, int const b ) {
  // Checks pre conditions.
  assert( a >= 0 );
  assert( b >= 0 );

  if ( a < b ) return gcd( b, a );

  if ( b == 0 ) return a;

  return gcd( b, a % b );
}
```

Performing an analysis on the run time I find that every operation is O(1) and hence we know the recurrence relation thus far is: T(n) = O(1) + ???. Now to analyze the recursive call, I am not sure how to interpret a (mod b) as my recursive call to properly state my recurrence relation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Algorithmic_efficiency

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At each recursive step, `gcd` will cut one of the arguments in half (at most). To see this, look at these two cases:

If `b >= a/2` then on the next step you'll have `a' = b` and `b' < a/2` since the `%` operation will remove `b` or more from `a`.

If `b < a/2` then on the next step you'll have `a' = b` and `b' < a/2` since the `%` operation can return at most `b - 1`.

So on each recursive step, `gcd` will cut one of the arguments in half (at most). This is O(log(N)) steps where N is the max of the initial `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

To analyze Euclidean GCD, you ought to use Fibonacci pairs: gcd(Fib[n], Fib[n - 1]) - Worst case scenario.

If you test your Euclidean GCD above, you'll end up with 24 recursive calls.

If you're accustomed to recurrence relations solving, the following might interest you:

[image]

With this study, one can't deduce the exact number of iterations for any dividend/divisor pair (hence the small Oh notation), but it guarantees that this upper bound is valid.
Generally, the lower bound is Omega(1) (When the divisor is **1**, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

A simple analysis and proof goes like this:

1. Show that if `Euclid(a,b)` takes more than `N` steps, then
   `a>=F(n+1)` and `b>=F(n)`, where `F(i)` is the `i`th Fibonacci
   number. 
   This can easily be done by Induction.
2. Show that `F(n)` ≥ φ<sup>n-1</sup>, again by
       Induction.
3. Using results of Step 1 and 2, we have b ≥ `F(n)` ≥
       φ<sup>n-1</sup> 
    Taking logarithm on both sides,
       log<sub>φ</sub>b ≥ n-1. 
    Hence proved, n ≤ 1 +
       log<sub>φ</sub>b

This bound can be improved.
No. of recursive calls in `EUCLID(ka,kb)` is the same as in `EUCLID(a,b)`, where `k` is some integer.
Hence, the bound is improved to 1 + log<sub>φ</sub>( b / gcd(a,b) ).